# how to recall the class that was removed previously

Tags: jquery

Some css classes which are removed previously using jquery for eg.

html

```
<div class="one someclass"></div>
<div class="two otherclass"></div>
<div class="one otherclass"></div>
<div class="two someclass"></div>
```

jquery

```
$('div').removeClass();
```

This will remove all classes.

Now I want to catch that previously applied class for specific class.

```
    $('div').addClass('someclass') 
      /* to which previously it was applied someclass in the above html
         that is add someclass to first class - one and last class -two*/
    $('div').addClass('otherclass') 
      /* to which previously it was applied otherclass in the above html
          that is add otherclass to first class - two and last class -one*/
```

**Edit**

How to do even if it was like this

```
<div class="one someclass"></div>
<div class="otherclass two"></div>
<div class="one otherclass"></div>
<div class="someclass one"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Save it before removing.

```
var classes = $("div")[0].className;

$('div').removeClass();

// ... Some Code Later

$('div').addClass(classes);
```

---

Addressing you problem word to word, You may save the all the classes with `someClass` as:

```
function saveClasses(className) {
      return $(className)[0].className.split(/\s+/)
           .filter(function(c) { return c!=className; }).join(" ");
}

var classes = saveClasses(".someClass");

var $div = $('.someClass').removeClass();

// Some Code Later

$div.addClass(classes);
```

This will add back all the classes except `someClass`.

Comment: This would add _all_ classes back, not just 'someclass'.

Comment: It still does not restore 'someclass', or explain how

Answer (score 1):

To do this I have created two `function`'s `removeAllClass` and `addOldClass`. While removing all `class` it's getting store in attribute called `oldClass` so we can use it while adding old `class`

Try this:

```
function removeAllClass(selector) {
   selector = $(selector);
   selector.removeClass(function(el, cs) {
        $('.'  + cs.split(' ').join('.')).attr('oldClass', cs).removeClass(cs);
    });
}
function addOldClass(cs) {
    $('*[oldClass*=' + cs + ']').each(function(i, v) {
       var el = $(v);
       if ($.inArray(cs, $(v).attr('oldClass').split(' '))) {
           el.addClass(cs);
       }
    });
}

removeAllClass('div');
addOldClass('otherclass');
```

Comment: +1. This is very similar to my solution except it saves it in another attribute instead of other classnames. That makes finding the classes to restore slightly harder, in exchange for being able to actually remove all classes (if that's important - extra classes shouldn't change anything)

Answer (score 0):

The problem with just removing all classes entirely is that it makes it very hard to find the set of elements you want to add the classes back to later.

That's a problem classes are ideally suited to solving - so I'd suggest automatically adding new classnames that are generated based on the current classnames - and instead of just removing all classes, replace them with these newly generated classnames.

For example, every element that had the `someclass` class will now have the `had-someclass` class instead.

Here's some code:

```
// replace all classes on all <div> elements with had-* classes instead
$('div').each(function() {
    // get the current classes
    var classes = this.className.split(/\s+/);
    for (var i=0; i<classes.length; i++) {
        // if it's not already a had-* class, make it one
        if (classes[i].substring(0, 4) != 'had-') {
            classes[i] = 'had-' + classes[i];
        }
    }
    // remove all classes, and add the had-* classes instead
    $(this).removeClass().addClass(classes.join(' '));
});
```

Then to add back selected missing classes, you could do something like this:

```
// find everything that used to have the 'someclass' class, and put it back
$('div.had-someclass').toggleClass('had-someclass someclass');
```

A fiddle showing this in use is here: http://jsfiddle.net/dy4rN/

Comment: Updated (again) with a better demo.